# Why were hot-stick downmoding to CSS, and the ability to use CSS for some control axes but not others, disabled during space-shuttle powered flight?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, flight-control, piloting

During ascent, if need be, a space shuttle’s flight controls could be switched from the normal, automatic control mode over to manual<sup>1</sup> control (known as *control-stick steering*, or *CSS*), allowing the crew to maintain control of the vehicle in the event of a flightpath-guidance-system failure or when performing manoeuvres not programmed into the shuttle’s flight-control software.

The ways in which a downmode from automatic to CSS mode could be performed, and the flexibility allowed when doing so, were considerably more restricted during powered flight than after engine shutdown:

> **2.5.1 Powered Flight (MM 102, MM 103, or MM 601)**
>
> CSS mode for the Digital Auto Pilot (DAP) is selected in powered flight by depressing any one of the four (two on each of panels F2 and F4) PITCH and ROLL/YAW CSS eyebrow panel pushbuttons.
>
> Depressing any of these four pushbuttons will mode **all three** Rotational Hand Controller (RHC) axes to CSS on both RHCs.
>
> **Independent moding of pitch or roll/yaw axes in powered flight is not possible. Either all are AUTO or all are CSS.**
>
> **NOTE:** The DAP status field in the upper left corner of the A/E PFD (Ascent/Entry Primary Flight Display) will read “CSS” instead of “AUTO” and be surrounded by a yellow box.
>
> **Hot-stick downmoding from AUTO to CSS, by just deflecting the RHC, is not possible in powered flight.**
>
> **2.5.2 Entry (MM 602, MM 603, MM 304, or MM 305)**
>
> **Either axis, pitch or roll/yaw, can be moded independently to CSS** by depressing the appropriate pushbutton on panels F2 or F4, **or by deflecting the RHC (hot-stick downmode) in the proper axis.**
>
> **NOTE:** The PITCH and R/Y status fields in the upper left corner of the A/E PFD will read “CSS” instead of “AUTO” and be surrounded by a yellow box.  *[[Space shuttle Contingency Aborts student handout](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383441main_contingency_aborts_21007_31007.pdf), page 20.  Section headings and “NOTE:” text bolded in original; all other bolding mine.]*

I don’t get the reasons for these restrictions; indeed, it seems like the ability to mode the vehicle’s pitch and roll/yaw axes independently would have been *more* important during powered flight (when the vehicle was holding a continuous large pitch-up<sup>2</sup> input in order to compensate for the pitch-down torque that would otherwise result from the engines’ grossly-offset position relative to the vehicle’s center of mass, and where it would seem to have been beneficial to be able to downmode roll/yaw control to CSS while keeping pitch control automatic, rather than having to release automatic pitch control - thus necessitating that one apply a compensatory pitch-up input on top of any roll/yaw component - just to manually roll and yaw the vehicle) than after engine burnout and ET separation (when there would be no such thrust-induced pitch mistrim to have to compensate for).  Was it merely due to the coders running out of space in the shuttles’ flight-control software?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Note that “manual control” merely means that the crew were hand-flying the vehicle rather than letting the autopilot do it; it does *not* mean that the crew were moving the flight-control surfaces and engine gimbals directly, as the orbiters’ joysticks (even in CSS mode) [had no direct connection to the flight controls themselves](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57122/22726).

<sup>2</sup>: Pitch-up in the orbiter’s (and crew’s) reference frame, that is, not as viewed from the ground, as, during powered flight, the vehicle would be in an inverted climb (for about the first third of powered flight) or inverted horizontal flight (for the remaining two-thirds until main-engine burnout).

Comment: Having flown a number (hundreds) of manual ascents in the Shuttle Mission Simulator, you *definitely* did not want to engage that mode by bumping the stick.  Also note that the Orbiter control system was a *rate command* system - putting in a constant stick input commanded a constant rate, not a constant attitude.

Comment: Yes, accidentally disengaging all attitude control by bumping into the RHC under the G-loads and vibrations of ascent doesn't sound fun. And I guess the reason not to allow partial manual control during ascent might have a lot to do with the tightly constrained flight envelope of the stack and the tremendous forces involved. As in, you would only ever switch to CSS when everything has already failed and you're on the way to LOCV.

Comment: @TooTea agreed, It was, to put it mildly, difficult to fly manually during first stage. The flight rules tell you to engage BFS instead of flying manually until T+1:30! To me, getting all axis control is normal, the question is really, why did they build in single axis control for entry?